# Jquery UI-Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-draggable

I am dynamically creating draggable div from java script and apending to div as below:

```
$("#draggable2").append("<div class='panel panel-default cardpanel' id='" + data.CardID + "panelcard' > <div style='background-color:#1946ba; color:#ffffff;' class='panel-heading' id='" + data.CardID + "'>" + "<input type'text' class='one' value=" + data.CardID+ "> "  + data.Title +"<label   data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='" +"Assigned Users:&#013;" + tab1 + "'   class='fa fa-users red-tooltip' style='font-size:20px;color:#f5f5f5; float:right;'> </label>" + "</div> <div    class='panel-body' id='" + data.CardID + "' >" + "<div class='col-xs-12' id='" + data.CardID + "'>" + data.Description  +  " </div> <span title='Create Child Cards' onclick='CreateChildcard(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:-14px;  margin-top:20%; border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-plus-circle'></span> <span title='Block Card' onclick='GetBlockcard(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:5px;border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></span> <span title='View Child Cards' onclick='ViewChildCards(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:5px;border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-cc'></span> <span title='Due Date' onclick='GetCalendercard(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:5px;border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-calendar'></span> <span title='Edit Card Details' onclick='EditCardDetails(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:5px;border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-edit'></span> </div>   </div> </div>  ");
     var id =data.CardID +"panelcard"

       $("#"+id).draggable(
               {
                    containment: "#cards",
                    scroll: false
            });

      using below  code to position dropped item


      ( function() {
   $( "#draggable").droppable({
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).append(ui.draggable.css({position: "relative", top:"2", left:"2"}))

    };
```

Everything is working fine but i also have a modal where in draggable's are in Modal-body created dynamically  using java script as below:

```
$("#draggablechild1").append("<div class='panel panel-default cardpanelchild' id='" + data.CardID + "panelchildcard' > <div style='background-color:#1946ba; color:#ffffff;' class='panel-heading' id='" + data.CardID + "'>" + "<input type'text' class='one' value=" + data.CardID+ "> "  + data.Title +"<label   data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='" +"Assigned Users:&#013;" + tab1 + "'   class='fa fa-users red-tooltip' style='font-size:20px;color:#f5f5f5; float:right;'> </label>" + "</div> <div    class='panel-body' id='" + data.CardID + "' >" + "<div class='col-xs-12' id='" + data.CardID + "'>" + data.Description  +  " </div>  <span title='Block Card' onclick='GetBlockcard(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:5px;border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></span>  <span title='Due Date' onclick='GetCalendercard(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:5px;border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-calendar'></span> <span title='Edit Child Card Details' onclick='EditChildCardDetails(this);' style='font-size:24px; margin-left:5px;border:none;color:#1946ba; z-index:100;'  class='fa fa-edit'></span> </div>   </div> </div> " );
        var id =data.CardID +"panelchildcard"

    $("#"+id).draggable({
        containment: '#childcards'});
```

When i drag items in modal-body item's are jumping out from Modal-body and appending to first droppable area on html page body. I want the draggable's to stay in modal body rather than jumping to different or previous droppable area

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but maybe it could help - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Comment: Thank you but I looking solution for jQuery UI draggable not to create draggable

Comment: this site may help you then. https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable